# ref is undefined React

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to access my email and password field through `ref` but I get an undefined value no matter what.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {  Button,
          Modal,
          ModalHeader,
          ModalBody,
          ModalFooter,
          Form,
          FormGroup,
          Input
       } from 'reactstrap';

class LoginModal extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.email = React.createRef();
    this.password = React.createRef();
    };

  login (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const email = this.email
    const password = this.password

    console.log(email, password)
  }


  render () {
    return (
      <Modal>
        <ModalHeader>Connexion</ModalHeader>
        <ModalBody>
        <Form onSubmit={this.login}>
          <FormGroup>
            <Input type="email" name="email"  ref={this.email} placeholder="Email" />
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup>
            <Input type="password" name="password" ref={this.password} placeholder="Mot de passe" />
          </FormGroup>
          <Button type="submit" color="primary">CONNEXION</Button>
        </Form>
        </ModalBody>
        <ModalFooter>
         Footer
        </ModalFooter>
      </Modal>
    )
  }
}

export default LoginModal
```

I am using react 16.5.2.

I did this according to the doc: [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

Comment: Is there are reason you are using refs instead of using controlled inputs?

Comment: I don't think so; just though it was the most straighforward way to access my input's value

Comment: bind `this.login`, also - use `innerRef` to get a reference to the underlying `input` behind the reactstrap component

Comment: is `innerRef` any better than `this.myref.current.value` ?

Comment: depends what you plan to do. eg, `.focus()` would only work on `innerRef` which returns the input, but Input has a value getter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the method inside your constructor:

```
this.login = this.login.bind(this)
```

And also to get ref value, you will use `current`

```
login (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const email = this.email
    const password = this.password

    console.log(email.current.value, password.current.value)
  }
```

Comment: the binding was the problem; thank you ! was so focused on the refs that I forgot to bind.